# Active Record query with nested association and includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a reservation system that allows the owner to blackout certain dates on certain properties. So, to generate availability across all properties for a specific date, I need to first see if there are any property_blackout_dates on that date.

```rb
class PropertyBlackoutDate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
end 

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :property_blackout_dates
end
```

Since I want all the Properties without a property_blackout_date for a specific date, I tried doing this:

```rb
date = "2020-02-22"
Property.includes(:property_blackout_dates).where.not(property_blackout_dates: {date: date}).references(:property_blackout_dates
```

But it just returns an empty object, even though I have Properties and PropertyBlackoutDates.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I'd probably go with a nested query:

```
Property.where.not(id: Property.select(:id).joins(:property_blackout_dates).where(property_blackout_dates: {date: date}))
```

Untested, but should execute in one query.

You could make this a scope to clean it up as well.

```
class Property < ActiveModel::Base
  # Example: Property.not_blacked_out(date)
  scope :not_blacked_out, ->(date) { where.not(id: select(:id).joins(:property_blackout_dates).where(property_blackout_dates: {date: date})) } 
end
```